# Aiml with python pattern doesn't recognise DON'T but recognise DO NOT

Tags: python-2.7, aiml

This works as expected

```
    <category>
     <pattern>DO NOT CALL ME *</pattern>
     <that>WHAT CAN I CALL YOU</that>
     <template>So what can I call you?</template>
    </category>
```

This throws an unmatched error

```
    <category>
      <pattern>DON'T CALL ME *</pattern>
      <that>WHAT CAN I CALL YOU</that>
      <template>So what can I call you?</template>
    </category>
```

I am obviously doing something stupid. Anyone know what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting that error because `'` is not escaped so Python thinks that the string ends there.
try escaping the `'` by adding a slash `\'`.

Comment: changed <pattern>DONT CALL ME *</PATTERN>. Then python code is  human_input = raw_input("Enter your message >> ").replace("\'',"")
print kernel.respond(human_input)